# Updating Google Firebase dependencies in Android project build.gradle file

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, gradle, dependency-management

I have been working on a project where I am trying to build a messaging application in Android Studio using Google Firebase. I previously had to restart the project due to an error after reaching this stage of the tutorial I have been following which requires you to add an implementation of the `'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.1.0'` (Or whatever the most recent version is) in my project gradle file and update the existing dependencies I am using accordingly.

I am still relatively new to app dev and as such don't want to mess up this project and start from scratch again by screwing up my gradle file. So could somebody show me what my build.gradle file should look like with the new dependency added and the existing dependencies correctly updated before syncing?

Info on adding the dependency can be found under this link, mainly under the 'Installation' and 'Dependencies' headings. https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android

My current gradle file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.conormcadorey.chatbox"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-beta01'

implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

//creates a rounded user profile image
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'

//ArthurHub - allows user to crop their profile image
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.+'

//Picasso - image uploader
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

ps - I appreciate that this may be a simple or obvious question, however when I attempted this myself I ended up having to rebuild the project from scratch so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Using Android Studio v3.1.3

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#compatibility-with-firebase--google-play-services-libraries):

As of version 4.1.0, FirebaseUI has the following dependency versions:

```
Library             Version
firebase-auth       16.0.1
play-services-auth  15.0.1
firebase-database   16.0.1
firebase-firestore  17.0.1
firebase-storage    16.0.1
```

Therfore change the following libraries:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
```

into this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
```

Also add the `firebase-core`:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
```

> Your app gradle file now has to explicitly list `com.google.firebase:firebase-core` as a dependency for Firebase services to work as expected.

Comment: I have done so accordingly and synced the gradle file, however the sync has failed and I have got an error message-- Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.2
Open File
Show in Project Structure dialog

Comment: use the following in the top level gradle file `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'` and sync

Comment: Thank you the sync has worked successfully! I have now only got a warning message -- "Warning: The app gradle file must have a dependency on com.google.firebase:firebase-core for Firebase services to work as intended." Would you recommend adding the 'firebase-core' dependency to my gradle to ensure there are no future problems? I would normally go ahead and add it, but I am still concerned about making a mistake again after restarting the project.

Comment: yes you need to add it as said in the answer, after you upgrade the google-service to 4.0.1 you shouldn't have any problems